Is it possible in Apache Superset to use a metric defined within another metric?
I need to use a metric, for example, the start_date metric: min(date), within another metric that filters data from a query, for example, select sum(value) filter (where date = start_date). Is it possible? Thank you.
I tried to use one metric within another, but it throws an error saying the column does not exist.
